# Embedded Google Calendar not showing up on JQuery toggle or slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, google-calendar-api, slidetoggle

I would like to reveal an embedded Google Calendar with JQuery toggle() or slideToggle(), however only blank space appears

HTML

```
<span class="btn btn-purple btn-lg" id="showcalendar">View Calendar</span>

<div class="section section-calendar" id="calendarhide" style="display:none;">
<div class="container container-calendar">
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=EMAILHIDDEN%40gmail.com&ctz=Europe/Monaco" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div><!--container-->
</div><!--section-->
```

JQuery

```
$('#showcalendar').click(function(){
$('#calendarhide').slideToggle();
});
```

If I insert a word "test" instead of the iframe, the word shows up without any problem, i.e. it must be an issue with Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/YS3yyaQ7mhw) which stated that the best approach for Google Sites to creating a toggle (show/hide) button or div is by using jQuery coded into an html box.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.js"></script>

<button id='button'>NAME YOUR BUTTON</button>

<div id='text' style='display:none;'>
    <ul>
        <li>list 1</li>
        <li>list 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>

    $('#button').click(function(){
      if ($(this).text() === 'Read More') {
        $(this).text('Read Less');
        $('#text').toggle("fast");
      }
      else {
        $(this).text('Read More');
        $('#text').toggle("fast");
      }
    });

</script>
```